# Update Teamcity parameter using powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-rest-api

I want to update the parameter value in the Teamcity build template.

I tried the following URL:

[PUT] [http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/app/rest/buildTypes/{BuildTypeName}/parameters/{ParameterName}/{ParameterValue}](http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/app/rest/buildTypes/%7BBuildTypeName%7D/parameters/%7BParameterName%7D/%7BParameterValue%7D)

By trying this I'm facing the following error

> 403 Forbidden: Responding with 403 status code due to failed CSRF check: authenticated PUT request is made, but neither tc-csrf-token parameter nor X-TC-CSRF-Token header are provided.
>
> For a temporary workaround, you can set internal property teamcity.csrf.paranoid=false  and provide valid Origin=http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080 header with your request

Please suggest how update the parameter value in Teamcity

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/csrf-protection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the "Origin=http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080" in the header solved the issue